# Check if user input is in txt file, with batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am making a chat style system in batch for LAN networked computers. 
I want to check if a username is taken or not and if it is not allow it to be picked, How can I check if what the user inputs in this line (set /p name2=)
I have tried this in a test file, but cant get it to work

```
:startup
set "fail="
set "name2="
set /p "name2=Enter Your Username: "
cls
findstr /b /e /l /c:"%name2%" <"Users.twml" >nul || set fail=1
if defined fail (
goto nope
)


:yes
cls
echo yes, you can use that
echo >> Users.twml %name2%
pause
goto endoftest



:nope
cls
echo thats taken try again
ping locahost -n 3 >nul
goto startup
```

The issues is it always goes to nope, even if name isn't taken. The Users.twml file is created and if i manually put :Yes where it will load after the user picks name it saves the name to file.

What i want is: user picks name, it checks if its in file(taken) if yes retry with a goto startup, if its not taken, write it to the file and continue on. preferably with a goto section command so i can specify where to go...

The code block above is what i need help with ^^^

The stuff below is what i currently use and it works just no name verification.

Here is the block i currently have for use name selection that is working without the name verification

```
:startup
cls
echo Pick A UserName
echo 1-16 Character limit.
set /p name2=
if "!name2!" == "" goto startup
if "!name2!" == " " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "  " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "   " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "    " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "     " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "      " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "       " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "        " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "         " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "          " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "           " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "            " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "             " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "              " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "               " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "                " goto startup
if not "!name2:~16!" == "" goto over

REM continues on after name picked if matches above requirements with stuff below

echo >> Connected.twml [System] %computername%:%username% Has joined as: %name2%
echo >> Directory.twml [System] %name2% Has joined the chat.
goto chat
```

This is what i'm trying to go for to give you a visual idea.
And currently is doesn't work

```
:startup
cls
echo Pick A UserName
echo 1-16 Character limit.
set "fail="
set /p name2=
if "!name2!" == "" goto startup
if "!name2!" == " " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "  " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "   " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "    " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "     " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "      " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "       " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "        " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "         " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "          " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "           " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "            " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "             " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "              " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "               " goto startup
if "!name2!" == "                " goto startup
if not "!name2:~16!" == "" goto over
REM all the above works, now lets try to check if its taken
findstr /b /e /l /c:"%name2%" <"Users.twml" >nul || set fail=1
if defined fail (
goto nope
)

REM continues on after name picked if matches above requirements with stuff below

echo >> Connected.twml [System] %computername%:%username% Has joined as: %name2%
echo >> Directory.twml [System] %name2% Has joined the chat.
echo >> Users.twml %name2%
goto chat

:nope
cls
echo thats taken try again
ping locahost -n 3 >nul
goto startup
```

This is what the inside of users.twml looks if :yes if ran correctly

```
username1
username2
username3
username4
```

@@@@@@@@@@ New edits blow here @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

All fixed and working i used %user2% in text file and %name2% in main file so no wonder they dont work together. still dont understand findstr though... This is why you dont write any form of code at 1am with low sleep i guess :)

Comment: It would be wise to provide an example of your `Users.twml` file, as it suggests a markup language similar to XML.

Comment: added how the file looks, its just added to the file by batch line >> %twml% echo %user2%

Answer (score 2):

You've confused `||` and `&&` (I do too, which is why I never use them)

`&&` means "if succeeded" ie, `errorlevel` is `0`. `||` means the opposite.

`findstr` will "succeed" if the target string *is* found. (um, sure you don't want `/i` - and `/b /e` is equivalent to `/x`)

If you fix the `||` to `&&` then - well, perhaps `found` rather than `fail`...

BUT

your code will still not work because the data you are recording in your file will be preceded by a space. Any characters in a `echo` line, once the redirection and target definitions are removed other than the first space are redirected to the file. Your code is

```
echo
space
redirection specifier including filename
space
%user2%
```

so, removing the redirection string and the first space leaves <kbd>Space</kbd>%user2%

to fix use

```
>> %twml% echo %user2%
```

ie

```
redirection specifier including filename
space
echo
space
%user2%
```

The first space separates the redirection voodoo from the `echo` instruction, and the second separates the `echo` from the required string.

---

Here's my test setup, using your original approach, with `cls`, delays removed and using a file that's convenient for my system

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
:startup
SET "twml=u:\users.twml"
set "fail="
set "user2="
set /p "user2=Enter Your Username: "
REM cls
IF NOT DEFINED user2 GOTO :EOF 
findstr /X /l /c:"%user2%" <"%twml%" >nul && set fail=1
if defined fail (
 goto nope
)


:yes
REM cls
echo yes, you can use that
>> %twml% echo %user2%
goto :eof



:nope
REM cls
echo thats taken try again
:: ping locahost -n 3 >nul
goto startup
GOTO :EOF
```

works fine for me!

Comment: i solved the space being added to users.twml with your voodoo trick, but my main issue of findstr still not working right is still there

Comment: I scrapped findstr to just use find, its working but i got another issue now with your voodoo trick, perhaps you know why, posted above is my new solution that is working in test but not the production file

Comment: found where ECHO is off. is from it was caused by echo before %user2% stop it by using: >> Users.twml echo. %user2%   but %user2% is not saving to the users.twml file it just saves a blank line as if echo. printed out in cmd (blank line)

Comment: copy/pasted your new solution using my first method to a new file, ran it when i enter a name it just closes, doesnt write to file, nothing just exits.